# Elm browser application not displaying

Tags: elm

I copied the HTML from [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/), and the Elm code from [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/navigation.html). The only change I made to the Elm code was the addition of the first line - module Main exposing (..). My IDE was complaining. Yet when I open index.html in a browser, I get a blank screen and the title of the page is still "Main". What am I doing wrong?

Here is my project structure

```
new-project
  elm-stuff
  src
    Main.elm
  elm.json
  index.html
  main.js
```

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Main</title>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>var app = Elm.Main.init();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Main.elm:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Browser.Navigation as Nav
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Url



-- MAIN


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
  Browser.application
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    , onUrlChange = UrlChanged
    , onUrlRequest = LinkClicked
    }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
  { key : Nav.Key
  , url : Url.Url
  }


init : () -> Url.Url -> Nav.Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags url key =
  ( Model key url, Cmd.none )



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = LinkClicked Browser.UrlRequest
  | UrlChanged Url.Url


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    LinkClicked urlRequest ->
      case urlRequest of
        Browser.Internal url ->
          ( model, Nav.pushUrl model.key (Url.toString url) )

        Browser.External href ->
          ( model, Nav.load href )

    UrlChanged url ->
      ( { model | url = url }
      , Cmd.none
      )



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions _ =
  Sub.none



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Browser.Document Msg
view model =
  { title = "URL Interceptor"
  , body =
      [ text "The current URL is: "
      , b [] [ text (Url.toString model.url) ]
      , ul []
          [ viewLink "/home"
          , viewLink "/profile"
          , viewLink "/reviews/the-century-of-the-self"
          , viewLink "/reviews/public-opinion"
          , viewLink "/reviews/shah-of-shahs"
          ]
      ]
  }


viewLink : String -> Html msg
viewLink path =
  li [] [ a [ href path ] [ text path ] ]
```

EDIT per answer by @pdamoc. I am trying to use elm-live to compile and display the elm file. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, with npm version 6.14.9, node version v8.10.0.

I get this error using elm-live:

```
$ elm-live src/Main.elm --pushstate
events.js:239
    throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
    at _addListener (events.js:239:11)
    at Server.addListener (events.js:297:10)
    at new Server (_http_server.js:269:10)
    at Object.createServer (http.js:34:10)
    at model (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-live/lib/src/start.js:259:75)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-live/node_modules/crocks/core/compose.js:8:14
    at settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-live/node_modules/crocks/Async/index.js:151:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-live/node_modules/crocks/Async/index.js:27:62
    at fork (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-live/node_modules/crocks/Async/index.js:155:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-live/node_modules/crocks/Async/index.js:224:16
```

Comment: There are too many unknowns here. Just as a starting point, you should look into: 1) whether `main.js` got loaded successfully, 2) whether it contains the JS produced by the Elm compiler. And report back your findings. (How your project is deployed could also be relevant, and certainly will be if the problem is `main.js` returning a 404.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I can see main.js under Sources in the browser, and it references elm. It matches what I see in my project as well.

Comment: It looks like something is preventing elm-live from starting. Maybe it is a permissions thing. Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with this error, maybe some else can provide further information. 

What OS/node version are you on?

Comment: It works if I use 'elm reactor'. What is elm reactor doing that simply opening the 'index.html' file in the browser does not?

Comment: `elm reactor` is not designed to be used for applications (elm apps that use navigation). 

It is worth noting that you are on an unsupported node version (v8 branch stopped maintenance in January 2020). If possible, upgrade to the latest LTS version (v14).

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to install an older version of `elm-live`. `3.2.3` might work on node v8. From the `elm-live` readme it seams that elm-live v4.x (latest) requires at least node v10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a webserver that would serve the `index.html` on every path that is requested. The easiest way is to install `elm-live` globally and then start it like `elm-live src/Main.elm --pushstate`

Without serving `index.html` on every path (let's say you use `live-server`), if you navigate to an internal path and reload you will get a 404.

Comment: edited answer showing version info on my OS, node, and npm.